# Spring Webflow Errors occurred during input mapping

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I'm doing a flow with Spring Webflow, however in the last step when the application goes to save the data, sometimes generated the next exception :

The main problem is what this error I can't generate in my environment local. Could you tell me some suggestion about this?. Thank you :)

> **2014-01-20 10:30:59,662 [ERROR] [EceetWebFilter.java:45] Error org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.FlowInputMappingException: Errors
>   occurred during input mapping on startup of the
>   'inmueble/ediciondatosbasicos' flow; errors = [[RequiredError@2f32178b
>   code = 'required', error = true, errorCause = [null], originalValue =
>   [null], mappedValue = [null]]]**  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>   ~[servlet-api.jar!/:5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA
>   date=200905221053)]   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   ~[servlet-api.jar!/:5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA
>   date=200905221053)]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)

This is the Web Flow view where the **data model is mapping**

```
<body>
<div id="contenedorppal_publicar">
    <div id="publicar_contppal">
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <form:form modelAttribute="publicacion" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1" onsubmit="return validateInputs( this );" action="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=continuar" method="post">
        <form:hidden path="idSector"/>
        <form:hidden path="nombreCiudadGeo"/>
        <form:hidden path="direccionGeo"/>
        <form:hidden path="zonaGeo"/>
        <form:hidden path="sectorGeo"/>
        <form:hidden path="barrioGeo"/>
        <form:hidden path="coordenada"/>
        <form:hidden path="caracteristicasGenerales"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="${publicacion.idInmueble}" id="idInmueble">

        <form:hidden path="caracteristicasEspecificas"/>
        <div class="publicar_cont_registrorr" id="divLocalizacionInmueble">
            <div class="tooltip"></div>
                <div class="publicar_registror">
                    <form:errors path="caracteristicasGenerales" cssClass="errorPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/>
                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <h2 id="headerLocalizacionInmueble">&raquo; Localización del inmueble</h2>
                    <p>Ingrese la siguiente informaci&oacute;n para publicar su propiedad en metrocuadrado.com. Los datos con  <b class="publicar_asterisco_popup">*</b> son obligatorios</p>

                    <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divCategoriaInmueble">
                        <form:label path="categoriaInmueble" title="Categor&iacute;a Inmueble">Categor&iacute;a Inmueble</form:label>
                        <form:select path="categoriaInmueble" items="${categoriasInmueble}" itemLabel="label" itemValue="id" id="ddlCategoriaInmueble" disabled="true" onchange="javascript:setControlPack( this.value )"/>
                        <span class="publicar_asterisco">*</span>
                        <form:errors path="categoriaInmueble" cssClass="errorValidacionPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divDireccion">
                        <form:label path="direccion" title="Dirección del inmueble">Direcci&oacute;n</form:label>
                        <form:input path="direccion" id="direccion" onkeypress="return validateAlphaNumericSpecial(event)"  readonly="true" maxlength="150" /><span class="publicar_asterisco"> *</span>
                        <form:errors path="direccion" cssClass="errorValidacionPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/> 
                     </div>

                    <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divDepartamento">
                        <label for="idRegion" title="Nombre del departamento">Departamento</label>
                        <form:select path="idRegion"  items="${regiones}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="label" disabled="true"  onchange="javascript:traerCiudadesXRegion();" /><span class="publicar_asterisco">*</span>
                        <form:errors path="idRegion" cssClass="errorValidacionPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divCiudad">
                        <label for="idCiudad" title="Nombre de la ciudad">Ciudad</label>
                        <form:select path="idCiudad" disabled="true"  items="${ciudades}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="label"/><span class="publicar_asterisco">*</span>
                        <form:errors path="idCiudad" cssClass="errorValidacionPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/> 
                    </div>

                     <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divTipoNegocio">
                        <form:label path="idTipoNegocio" title="Tipo de Negocio">Tipo de Negocio</form:label>
                        <form:select path="idTipoNegocio" items="${tiposNegocio}" itemLabel="label" itemValue="id" onchange="mostrarCaracteristicasGenerales()"/>
                        <span class="publicar_asterisco">*</span>
                        <form:errors path="idTipoNegocio" cssClass="errorValidacionPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/> 
                     </div>

                    <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divTipoInmueble">
                        <form:label path="idTipoInmueble" title="Tipo del inmueble">Tipo del inmueble</form:label>
                        <form:select path="idTipoInmueble" items="${tiposInmueble}" itemLabel="label" itemValue="id" disabled="true" onchange="setTipoInmuebleControlPack(this.value);mostrarCaracteristicasGenerales()"/> <span class="publicar_asterisco">*</span>
                        <form:errors path="idTipoInmueble" cssClass="errorValidacionPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divComentarios">
                        <form:label path="comentario" title="Descripci&oacute;n">Descripci&oacute;n</form:label>                    
                        <form:textarea path="comentario" onkeydown="return validarCTRL(event)" oncontextmenu="return false" onkeypress="validateMaxLenght( this, 500 );return validateRegExp( event, /^[a-zA-ZñÑ-áéíóú\/\,\.\ ]$/ )" style="height: 130px;" /><b class="publicar_asterisco_popup">*</b>                                                         
                        <form:errors path="comentario" cssClass="errorValidacionPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/> 
                        <div class="clear"></div>   
                    </div>

                    <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divTiempoPublicacion">
                        <label for="idTiempoPublicacion" title="Nombre de la ciudad">Tiempo de publicaci&oacute;n</label>

                      <c:if test="${publicacion.estaPublicado eq 'S' }">                      
                        <form:select path="idTiempoPublicacion" disabled="true"   items="${tiempos}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="label"/><span class="publicar_asterisco">*</span>                        
                      </c:if>
                      <c:if test="${publicacion.estaPublicado ne 'S'}">
                        <form:select path="idTiempoPublicacion"  items="${tiempos}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="label"/><span class="publicar_asterisco">*</span>                     
                      </c:if>
                     <form:errors path="idTiempoPublicacion" cssClass="errorValidacionPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/> 
                    </div>

                     <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divNombreComunBarrio">
                        <form:label path="nombreComunBarrio" title="Nombre común del barrio">Nombre com&uacute;n del barrio</form:label>
                        <form:input path="nombreComunBarrio" onkeypress="return validateAlpha(event)"  maxlength="150"/><span class="publicar_asterisco"> *</span>
                        <form:errors path="nombreComunBarrio" cssClass="errorValidacionPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/> 
                     </div>

                     <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divEstrado">                
                        <form:label path="estrato" title="Estrato">Estrato</form:label>
                        <form:input path="estrato" maxlength="100"/><span class="publicar_asterisco"> *</span>
                        <form:errors path="estrato" cssClass="errorValidacionPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/> 
                     </div>

                    <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divTelefono">
                        <form:label path="telefono" title="Tel&eacute;fono">Tel&eacute;fono</form:label>
                        <form:input path="telefono" onkeypress="return validateRegExp( event, /[0-9]/ )"  maxlength="150"/><span class="publicar_asterisco"> *</span>
                        <form:errors path="telefono" cssClass="errorValidacionPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/> 
                     </div>

                    <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divCapacidad">
                        <form:label path="capacidad" title="Capacidad">Capacidad</form:label>
                        <form:input path="capacidad" tipo="numerico" onkeypress="return validateRegExp( event, /[0-9]/ )" onkeyup="formatNumber( this, event )"  maxlength="150"/><span class="publicar_asterisco"> *</span>
                        <form:errors path="capacidad" cssClass="errorValidacionPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/> 
                     </div>

                    <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divTitulo">
                        <form:label path="titulo" title="T&iacute;tulo">T&iacute;tulo</form:label>
                        <form:input path="titulo" onkeypress="return validateRegExp( event, /^[0-9a-zA-ZñÑ\/\:\.\-\_\ \?\=\&\%]$/ )"  maxlength="150"/><span class="publicar_asterisco"> *</span>
                        <form:errors path="titulo" cssClass="errorValidacionPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/> 
                     </div>

                     <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divInmuebleCompartido" >
                        <form:label path="inmuebleCompartido" title="Inmueble Compartido">Inmueble Compartido</form:label>
                        <form:radiobutton path="inmuebleCompartido" value="S" title="Si" onchange="inmuebleCompartidoControlPack(this.value)" />
                        <label  class="radio"> Si </label>
                        <form:radiobutton path="inmuebleCompartido" value="N" title="No" onchange="inmuebleCompartidoControlPack(this.value)"/>
                        <label  class="radio"> No </label>
                     </div>
                     <div class="clear" id="divInmuebleCompartido2"></div>

                     <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divPrecioNoche">
                            <form:label path="precioNoche" id="precioNocheTotal" title="Precio Noche">Precio Noche <b style="font-size: 9px;">(Acomodación total)</b>
                            </form:label>
                            <form:label path="precioNoche" id="precioNocheSencilla" title="Precio Noche">Precio Noche <b style="font-size: 9px;">(Acomodación sencilla)</b>
                            </form:label>
                        <form:input path="precioNoche" tipo="numerico" onkeypress="return validateRegExp( event, /[0-9]/ )" maxlength="150"/><span class="publicar_asterisco"> *</span>
                        <form:errors path="precioNoche" cssClass="errorValidacionPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/> 
                     </div>

                   <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divUploadFileTarifa">
                        <form:label path="conFotos" title="Archivo de tarifas">Subir Archivo de Tarifas</form:label>
                        <input type="file" value="Seleccionar archivo" title="Seleccionar Archivo" onchange="setFileTarifa( this )" class="input_tooltip fileUpload" />
                        <input type='hidden' value='${publicacion.archivoTarifa}' name='archivoTarifa' id="hdnArchivoTarifa" />
                    </div>
                        <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divCaracteristicasPrinc">
                            <label for="nuevo">Caracteristicas principales</label>
                            <input type="hidden" value="${publicacion.caracteristicasPrincipales}" name="caracteristicasPrincipales" id="txtCaracteristicasPrincipales" />
                            <div class="tur_caracteristicas" id="divCaracteristicas">
                                <label title="Piscina">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="conPiscina" onclick="saveCaracteristicasPrincipales()" />
                                    Piscina
                                </label>
                                <label title="Cocina">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="conCocinaEquipada" onclick="saveCaracteristicasPrincipales()" />
                                    Cocina
                                </label>
                                <label title="Wifi">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="conWifi" onclick="saveCaracteristicasPrincipales()" />
                                    Wifi
                                </label>
                                <label title="Internet">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="conInternet" onclick="saveCaracteristicasPrincipales()" />
                                    Internet
                                </label>
                                <label title="Jacuzzi">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="conJacuzzi" onclick="saveCaracteristicasPrincipales()" />
                                    Jacuzzi
                                </label>
                                <label title="Cable TV">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="conCableTV" onclick="saveCaracteristicasPrincipales()" />
                                    Cable TV
                                </label>
                                <label title="Restaurante">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="conServicioRestaurante" onclick="saveCaracteristicasPrincipales()" />
                                    Restaurante
                                </label>
                                <label title="BBQ">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="conBBQ" onclick="saveCaracteristicasPrincipales()" />
                                    BBQ
                                </label>
                                <label title="Asensor">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="conAsensor" onclick="saveCaracteristicasPrincipales()" />
                                    Ascensor
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>

                        </div>

                </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="publicar_cont_registrorr" id="divDatosBasicosInmueble">
            <div class="publicar_registror">
                <h2 id="headerDatosbasicosInmueble">&raquo; Datos básicos del inmueble</h2>

                <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divEstadoInmueble">
                    <form:label path="esNuevo" title="Estado del inmueble">Estado del inmueble</form:label>
                    <form:radiobutton path="esNuevo" value="S"/>
                    <label  class="radio"> Nuevo </label>
                    <form:radiobutton path="esNuevo" value="N"/>
                    <label  class="radio"> Usado </label>
                 </div>

                 <div id="divCaracteristicasGenerales">

                 </div>

            </div>
            <div class="clear" id="divClear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="publicar_cont_registrorr" id="divComoLLegarInmueble">
            <div class="publicar_registror">
                <h2 id="headerComoLLegarInmueble">¿C&oacute;mo llegar?</h2>
                <p id="subComoLLegarInmueble">Usted puede subir un mapa con las indicaciones de como llegar al inmueble, debe ser un archivo, jpg, png, gif o pdf que no supere 2 mb.</p>

                <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divUploadFile">
                    <form:label path="conFotos" title="Subir archivo de mapa">Subir mapa</form:label>
                    <input type="file" value="Seleccionar archivo" title="Seleccionar archivo" onchange="setFileComollegar( this )" class="input_tooltip fileUpload" />
                    <input type='hidden' value='${publicacion.fileId}' name='fileId' id="hdnFileId" />
                    <!--a href="#" onclick="downloadFile()" >Descargar Archivo</a-->
                </div>

                <div class="publicar_filaform">
                    <form:label path="descripcionArchivo" title="Descripci&oacute;n">Descripci&oacute;n Archivo</form:label>                    
                    <form:textarea path="descripcionArchivo" onkeydown="return validarCTRL(event)" oncontextmenu="return false" onkeypress="validateMaxLenght( this, 500 );return validateRegExp( event, /[a-zA-Z0-9\ ]/ )" style="height: 130px;" /><b class="publicar_asterisco_popup">*</b>                                                          
                    <form:errors path="descripcionArchivo" cssClass="errorValidacionPublicacion" htmlEscape="false"/> 
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="clear" id="divClear"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="publicar_cont_registrorr" id="divDatosAdicionalesInmueble">
            <div class="publicar_registror">
                <h2 id="headerDatosAdicionales">&raquo; Datos adicionales y fotos</h2>
                <p id="subHeaderDatosBasicosInmueble">Seleccione las opciones deseadas si quiere ingresar datos adicionales, fotos y/o videos.</p>

                <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divDatosAdicionales">
                    <form:label path="datosAdicionales" title="Datos adicionales de su inmueble">Datos adicionales de su inmueble</form:label>
                    <form:radiobutton path="datosAdicionales" value="S"
        title="Incluir datos adicionales"
        onclick="javascript:mostrarCaracteristicasInmueble()" />
                    <label  class="radio"> Si </label>
                    <form:radiobutton path="datosAdicionales" value="N" title="No incluir datos adicionales"/>
                    <label  class="radio"> No </label>
                 </div>

                <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divFotosAdicionales">
                    <form:label path="conFotos" title="Fotos  y/o video">Fotos  y/o video</form:label>
                    <form:radiobutton path="conFotos" value="S" title="Incluir fotos y/o video"/>
                    <label  class="radio"> Si </label>
                    <form:radiobutton path="conFotos" value="N" title="No incluir fotos y/o video"/>
                    <label  class="radio"> No </label>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear" id="divClear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="publicar_cont_registrorr" id="divInmuebleDestacadoContainer">
            <div class="publicar_registror">
                <h2 id="headerInmuebleDestacado">&raquo; Destacar inmueble</h2>
                <p id="subHeaderInmuebleDestacado">&nbsp;</p>

                <div class="publicar_filaform" id="divInmuebleDestacado">
                    <form:label path="inmuebleDestacado" title="Fotos  y/o video">Destacar el inmueble</form:label>
                    <form:radiobutton path="inmuebleDestacado" value="S" title="Incluir fotos y/o video" onclick="InformarInmuebleDestacado();"/>
                    <label  class="radio"> Si </label>
                    <form:radiobutton path="inmuebleDestacado" value="N" title="No incluir fotos y/o video"/>
                    <label  class="radio"> No </label>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>

                <div class="publicar_filabtn" id="divActions">
                    <input  name="continuar" type="button" class="publicar_filabtn_input" id="Continuar" value="Continuar"
                        onclick="guardarCaracteristicasGenerales();uploadFiles();enviarFormulario();"/>
                </div>
            </form:form>
        </div>
        <iframe id="frmDownloadFile" name="frmDownloadFile" style="width: 1px; height: 1px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <iframe id="frmDownloadTarifa" name="frmDownloadTarifa" style="width: 1px; height: 1px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <form style="display: none" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/publicacion/uploadfile.do" id="formUploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="frmDownloadFile" method="POST"></form>
        <form style="display: none" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/publicacion/uploadfiletarifa.do" id="formUploadFileTarifa" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="frmDownloadTarifa" method="POST"></form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var strExec = "setTipoInmuebleControlPack(document.getElementById( 'idTipoInmueble' ).value);traerTipoinmuebleXcategoria();";
        strExec += "setControlPack( document.getElementById( 'ddlCategoriaInmueble' ).value );setTipoInmuebleControlPack(document.getElementById( 'idTipoInmueble' ).value);";
        strExec += "formatInputs( document );setInternalValues();";

        window.setTimeout( strExec, 500);

        function setInternalValues( ){

            var txtCaracteristicasPrincipales = document.getElementById( "txtCaracteristicasPrincipales" );
            var divCaracteristicas = document.getElementById( "divCaracteristicas" );
            var inputs = divCaracteristicas.getElementsByTagName( "INPUT" );
            var arrCaracteristicas = txtCaracteristicasPrincipales.value.split( ";" );

            for( var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++ ){

                for( var j=0; j<arrCaracteristicas.length; j++ ){

                    if( inputs[ i ].value == arrCaracteristicas[ j ] ){
                        inputs[ i ].checked = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            saveCaracteristicasPrincipales( );
        }

        function saveCaracteristicasPrincipales( ){
            var txtCaracteristicasPrincipales = document.getElementById( "txtCaracteristicasPrincipales" );
            var divCaracteristicas = document.getElementById( "divCaracteristicas" );
            var inputs = divCaracteristicas.getElementsByTagName( "INPUT" );
            var strCaracteristicas = "";

            for( var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++ ){
                if( inputs[ i ].checked ){
                    strCaracteristicas += ( strCaracteristicas != "" ? ";" : "" ) + inputs[ i ].value;
                }
            }

            txtCaracteristicasPrincipales.value = strCaracteristicas;
        }

        function uploadFiles( ){
            document.getElementById("formUploadFile").submit();
            document.getElementById('formUploadFileTarifa').submit();
        }

        function setFileTarifa( src ){

            var fileExt = (src.value.split(".") < 2 ? "unknow" : src.value.split(".")[src.value.split(".").length - 1]).toLowerCase();
            //document.getElementById( "fileUploaded" ).value = "";

            if (fileExt != "xls" && fileExt != "doc" && fileExt != "pdf" && fileExt != "docx" && fileExt != "xlsx" && fileExt != "ods" && fileExt != "odt" && fileExt != "txt") {

                src.value = "";
                alert("Solamente se pueden subir archivos xls, xlsx, docx, doc o pdf.");

                return;
            }

            var newInput = src.cloneNode(true);
            newInput.id = "archivoTarifa";
            newInput.name = "archivoTarifa";
            document.getElementById("formUploadFileTarifa").innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='${publicacion.archivoTarifa}." + fileExt + "' name='tfilename' />";
            document.getElementById("formUploadFileTarifa").appendChild(newInput);
            document.getElementById( "hdnArchivoTarifa" ).value = "${publicacion.archivoTarifa}." + fileExt;

        }

        function setFileComollegar(src) {
            var fileExt = (src.value.split(".") < 2 ? "unknow" : src.value.split(".")[src.value.split(".").length - 1]).toLowerCase();
            if (fileExt != "jpg" && fileExt != "jpeg" && fileExt != "png" && fileExt != "gif" && fileExt != "pdf") {

                src.value = "";
                alert("Solamente se pueden subir archivos jpg, png, gif o pdf.");

                return;
            }

            var newInput = src.cloneNode(true);
            newInput.id = "fileComollegar";
            newInput.name = "fileComollegar";
            document.getElementById("formUploadFile").innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='${publicacion.fileId}." + fileExt + "' name='filename' />";
            document.getElementById("formUploadFile").appendChild(newInput);
            document.getElementById( "hdnFileId" ).value = "${publicacion.fileId}." + fileExt;

        }

        function setControlPack(controlPack) {
            var strLocalizacionInmueble = "divLocalizacionInmueble,divDepartamento,";
            strLocalizacionInmueble += "divCiudad,divTiempoPublicacion,divCategoriaInmueble,divTiempoZZ,divDireccion,divNombreComunBarrio,divEstrado";

            var strDatosBasicosInmueble = "divDatosBasicosInmueble,headerDatosbasicosInmueble,divEstadoInmueble,divTipoNegocio,divEstadoInmueble,divCaracteristicasGenerales,divClear,selTipoNegocio";
            var strDatosAdicionalesInmueble = "divDatosadicionalesH2,divDatosAdicionales";
            var strCamposTurismo = "divComoLLegarInmueble,headerDatosbasicosInmueble,divLocalizacionInmueble,divDireccion,divDepartamento,";
            strCamposTurismo += "divCiudad,divTelefono,divTipoNegocio,divCapacidad,divTitulo,divPrecioNoche,divUploadFileTarifa,";
            strCamposTurismo += "divInmuebleDestacadoContainer,divCaracteristicasPrinc,divFotosVideosH2,divInmuebleCompartido";

            var strExtras = "divActions,divCategoriaInmueble";
            var arrLocalizacionInmueble = strLocalizacionInmueble.split(",");
            var arrDatosBasicosInmueble = strDatosBasicosInmueble.split(",");
            var arrDatosAdicionalesInmueble = strDatosAdicionalesInmueble.split(",");
            var arrCamposTurismo = strCamposTurismo.split(",");
            var arrExtras = strExtras.split(",");
            disableControlArr(arrCamposTurismo, false);
            disableControlArr(arrLocalizacionInmueble, true);
            disableControlArr(arrDatosBasicosInmueble, true);
            disableControlArr(arrDatosAdicionalesInmueble, true);
            disableControlArr(arrExtras, true);
        }

        function setTipoInmuebleControlPack(tipoInmuebleControlPack) {

            var inmuebleCompartido = "divInmuebleCompartido,divInmuebleCompartido2";
            var arrInmuebleCompartido = inmuebleCompartido.split(",");
            disableControlArr(arrInmuebleCompartido, false);

            if (tipoInmuebleControlPack == "2" || tipoInmuebleControlPack == "7") {

                disableControlArr(arrInmuebleCompartido, true);

            } else {

                disableControlArr(arrInmuebleCompartido, false);
            }
            inmuebleCompartidoControlPack('N');
        }

        function inmuebleCompartidoControlPack(compartidoControlPack) {
            var precioNocheSencilla = "precioNocheSencilla";
            var precioNocheTotal = "precioNocheTotal"
            var arrPrecioNocheSencilla = precioNocheSencilla.split(",");
            var arrPrecioNocheTotal = precioNocheTotal.split(",");
            disableControlArr(arrPrecioNocheSencilla, false);
            disableControlArr(arrPrecioNocheTotal, true);
        }

        function disableControlArr(arrControl, display) {

            for ( var kk = 0; kk < arrControl.length; kk++) {

                try {
                    document.getElementById(arrControl[kk]).style.display = (display ? "" : "none");
                }
                catch( ex ){}
            }
        }

        function InformarInmuebleDestacado( ){

            if( "${publicacion.idInmuebleDestacado}".replace( /\ /, "" ) != "" && "${publicacion.idInmuebleDestacado}" != "${publicacion.idInmueble}" )
                alert( "El Inmueble ${publicacion.idInmuebleDestacado} Será marcado como NO destacado cuando se publique el presente inmueble" );

        }


    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The error sounds like it's occurring at the beginning of a new flow, rather than at the end of one. Can you post the `<input>` portion of your "inmueble/ediciondatosbasicos" flow configuration?

Comment: I added the code ;) . I will review every field in the mapping.